# Laravel-websocket connect with Flutter

Tags: laravel-5, flutter, dart, websocket

can someone help me by connecting the laravel-websocket package with Flutter ?, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Pusher Websocket Flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/pusher_websocket_flutter) package.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Pusher Websocket Flutter package.

pusher_websocket_flutter: ^0.1.1

try {

```
  await Pusher.init(

      "Appid",
      PusherOptions(
        auth: PusherAuth(url, headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
        }),
        cluster: "ap2",
        encrypted: true,
      ),
      enableLogging: true);
} on PlatformException catch (e) {
  print(e.message);
}

Pusher.connect(onConnectionStateChange: (x) async {
  print(x.currentState);
}, onError: (x) {
  debugPrint("Error: ${x.exception}");
});
channel = await Pusher.subscribe(
    'private-message-1'}');
channel.bind('newmessage', (onEvent) {
print(onEvent.data)

});
```